# Cant add Office.Interop.Word (Version 14) Reference to my site

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to add the "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" reference to my site. Doing it trough the .NET references tab: both a Version 12 and a Version 14 appears. I can add the v12 and it appears in the Bin folder no problems. If I try to add the v14 it wouldn't put the DLL in the bin folder, but it updates the config file causing the YSOD: [image]
The dlls are where they are supposed to be so if I try to browse for the DLL instead of adding it through the .NET tab it still wouldn't do it.

I'm doing this trough a VS10, the computer has Office 2010 installed.

Comment: I suppose you would need to explicitly set the *Copy Local* property of the assembly reference to *true*, such that the DLL will be copied to your `bin` output directory. (I would guess that the v12 DLL is not registered in the GAC, leading to VS initially setting *Copy Local* to *true*, while the v14 version is registered in the GAC, leading to *Copy Local* being initially *false* for that assembly reference. But I could be totally wrong.)

Comment: Using the `Office.Interop` on any kind of server is not (officially) supported by microsoft, and generally also very prone to errors (especially when multiple users are using the site at the same time). Personally I'd strongly suggest to look into an alternative approach, for example like using `OpenXML` or a similar library which operates directly on the files and doesn't require an installed Microsoft Office application on the server.